# Changing hovering behavior in scss

Tags: html, sass

How can I make the "Menu" Button remain in hover as long as the mouse/pointer remains in the menu? When the pointer points on Twitter for example I want the menu button to show Home.

Like this:
[image]

And not like this:
[image]

This is the Codepen example: https://codepen.io/fotios_tragopoulos/pen/YzWyZJj

This is the code:

```css
body {
  background-color: #010101;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  margin: 20px;
}

.menu {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  &:hover {
    pointer-events: all;
    .spacer {
      &:before {
        width: 100%;
        transition-delay: 0s;
      }
    }
    .item {
      opacity: 1;
      top: 0px;
      &:nth-child(1) {
        transition-delay: 0.25s;
      }
      &:nth-child(2) {
        transition-delay: 0.3s;
      }
      &:nth-child(3) {
        transition-delay: 0.35s;
      }
      &:nth-child(4) {
        transition-delay: 0.4s;
      }
      &:nth-child(5) {
        transition-delay: 0.45s;
      }
      &:nth-child(6) {
        transition-delay: 0.5s;
      }
      &:nth-child(7) {
        transition-delay: 0.55s;
      }
      &:nth-child(8) {
        transition-delay: 0.6s;
      }
      &:nth-child(9) {
        transition-delay: 0.65s;
      }
      &:nth-child(10) {
        transition-delay: 0.7s;
      }
    }
  }
}

.label {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  pointer-events: all;
}

.spacer {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  &:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;
    height: 1px;
    width: 0%;
    transition: width 0.25s ease;
    transition-delay: 0.7s;
  }
}

.item {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 30px;
  top: 10px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease, top 0.5s ease;
  transition-delay: 0;
  &:hover {
    span {
      color: #ff0000;
    }
  }
  &:nth-child(1) {
    transition-delay: 0.45s;
  }
  &:nth-child(2) {
    transition-delay: 0.4s;
  }
  &:nth-child(3) {
    transition-delay: 0.35s;
  }
  &:nth-child(4) {
    transition-delay: 0.3s;
  }
  &:nth-child(5) {
    transition-delay: 0.25s;
  }
  &:nth-child(6) {
    transition-delay: 0.2s;
  }
  &:nth-child(7) {
    transition-delay: 0.15s;
  }
  &:nth-child(8) {
    transition-delay: 0.1s;
  }
  &:nth-child(9) {
    transition-delay: 0.05s;
  }
  &:nth-child(10) {
    transition-delay: 0s;
  }
}

span {
  transition: color 0.5s ease;
}

.btn-flip {
  opacity: 1;
  outline: 0;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  text-transform: uppercase;
  &:hover {
    &:after {
      opacity: 1;
      transform: translateY(0) rotateX(0);
    }
    &:before {
      opacity: 0;
      transform: translateY(50%) rotateX(90deg);
    }
  }
  &:after {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 100%;
    color: #323237;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.5s;
    position: absolute;
    background: #adadaf;
    content: attr(data-back);
    transform: translateY(-50%) rotateX(90deg);
  }
  &:before {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    color: #adadaf;
    display: block;
    padding: 0 30px;
    line-height: 40px;
    transition: 0.5s;
    position: relative;
    background: #323237;
    content: attr(data-front);
    transform: translateY(0) rotateX(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <a href="#" class="label btn-flip" data-back="Home" data-front="Menu"></a>
  <div class="spacer"></div>
  <div class="item"><span>Twitter</span></div>
  <div class="item"><span>Instagram</span></div>
  <div class="item"><span>Flickr</span></div>
  <div class="item"><span>Behance</span></div>
  <div class="item"><span>MixCloud</span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the same rules inside `.menu`:

```
.menu {
...
  &:hover {
    .btn-flip {
      &:after {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateY(0) rotateX(0);
      }
      &:before {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateY(50%) rotateX(90deg);
      }
    }
```